# AffineTransformation: set rotation to certain angle

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I set rotation of AffineTransformation to certain angle?
I have tried to obtain the difference between target angle and current angle and then apply CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, rotateTo) :

```
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = self.view.transform;

long double alpha = atan2l(rotationTransform.b, rotationTransform.a);
rotateTo = M_PI_2-alpha;

rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, rotateTo);
```

But because of rounding error I do not receive exactly the target angle :(

Comment: The angle should be accurate enough for visual effects. Are you using it for some other calculation?

Comment: Yes I want to use it in other calculations. In worst case I can use some kind of rounding error threshold. But it would be better to use more accurate approach if exists :)

Comment: The transform matrices (CGAffineTransform and CATransform3D) are only meant for visual calculations. Thus, they only use `CGFloat`s (defined as either float or double depending on if its's 32-biy bit or 64-bit applications) for their values.